# How do I close or delete a question that I have asked?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

How do I close or delete a question that I have asked?

Because I have found answers to it already and would not want to be downvoted...

Comment: There should be a "delete" link beneath the list of tags on the post.

Comment: What about writing an answer yourself instead?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/248731

Answer (score 19):

The first question to answer, should you really delete it?

- If it's a duplicate and might be useful as a sign-post, close it as such an leave it.
  As you are below 50 rep, just post a comment with the target and ask for help, mentioning that problem.
  You can finish it the moment the first one flagged or close-voted as duplicate.
- Else if it might be helpful to others, write a self-answer if there's no good answer yet.
  If there is one, accept the best and be done.
- Finally, if really none of the above holds, cleaning it up yourself instead of waiting for others to do it *for you* is preferable. That's at best damage-control though, minimizing damage to the community (needless extra-work) and you (loss of priviliges).
  There's a gray delete-link directly below the post, above any comments.